# SQL query to show data only for today?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to automate a query without anyone changing the date manually. I have tried "GETDATE()" to no avail. I plan to use Google Sheets script editor to automate this task.
Here's a portion of the code where we change the date manually:

```
Left Join
OrderType ON SalesOrder.OrderTypeID = OrderType.OrderTypeID
Left Join
Location On EventRef.LocationID = Location.LocationID
Inner Join
Client On Location.ClientID = Client.ClientID
Inner Join
RequestSource On SalesOrder.RequestSourceID = RequestSource.RequestSourceID

WHERE 
EventRef.EventDateTime > '11-Oct-21 0:00:00 AM' 
AND EventRef.EventDateTime < '11-Oct-21 23:59:59 PM' 
AND OrderStatus.OrderStatusName <> 'Added in error'
AND OrderStatus.OrderStatusName <> 'Cancelled;
```

Comment: What's wrong with `GETDATE()`?

Comment: Have you tried converting in the where clause? Something like ```CONVERT(DATE, EventRef.EventDateTime) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())```

Comment: @d0little Converting a column used in a predicate is a bad idea, because it's much harder to use indexes. Better to do as Larnu has suggested below: a half-open interval

Comment: @Larnu When using "GETDATE( )" the query doesn't stop, which is not what I need.

Comment: Show us your actual query then, @DavidBill7 . You *aren't* doing something like storing your dates in something that isn't a date and time data type, are you..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GETDATE`/`SYSDATETIME` or `GETUTCDATE`/`SYSUTCDATETIME` or even `SYSDATEIMEOFFSET` (which depends on your data) is what you want and some *very* simply date logic:

```sql
...
WHERE EventRef.EventDateTime >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
  AND EventRef.EventDateTime < CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()))
...
```